# How to send multiple clicks in a single web page using PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS 2.1.1 to take screenshots of web pages.

What I need on [this particular page](http://www.public.fr/Dossiers/Influenceurs-Public/Tous-les-influenceurs-Public/Influenceur-Public-n-56-Raphael-Spezzotto-Simacourbe-l-homme-ideal-a-un-nom-1318898) is to click several times on a div element in order to slide pictures in a diaporama, by using the following code in a page.evaluate block :

```
page.open(url, function () {
    page.evaluate(function() { 
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.querySelector("div.linksNavNext.linksNav.icon-fleche-suiv").click();
            }, 500);
        }
    });       

    setTimeout(function(){
        page.render('url.png');
        phantom.exit();
    }, 2000);
});
```

As you see I try to get the 10th picture in the diaporama by sending 10 times the click event. But what I get is just the second picture. It seems the click event is sent only once, despite the for loop.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you doing it inside of page.evaluate?

Comment: @Vaviloff: Yes !

Answer (score 0):

It seems all 10 of your clicks are executed in just 500 ms. You need to postpone timeout:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector("div.linksNavNext").click();
  }, 500 * i);
}
```

Comment: There is some progress indeed, now I see the 4th picture... It seems there is an event called 'onChangeDiapo' after the click is sent. Maybe I have to wait for this event before sending the next click ?

Comment: Maybe. Maybe you should wait longer than 500ms between clicks. In this answer I just corrected the code your provided. If you gave more info on your task with code samples, script name and version then it could be another answer.

Comment: I'm just using the [rasterize sample code](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) from the PhantomJS GitHub. The page I'm trying to render with a specific picture in the diaporama is [this one](http://www.public.fr/Dossiers/Influenceurs-Public/Tous-les-influenceurs-Public/Influenceur-Public-n-56-Raphael-Spezzotto-Simacourbe-l-homme-ideal-a-un-nom-1318898). I tried to wait longer than 500ms to no avail...